# Is lock_guard a RAII implementation or it is used to implement RAII?

Tags: c++, c, design-patterns, raii

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) (and some other sources) states:

> In RAII, holding a resource is tied to object lifetime: resource allocation (acquisition) is done during object creation (specifically initialization), by the constructor, while resource deallocation (release) is done during object destruction, by the destructor. If objects are destructed properly, resource leaks do not occur.

However, the example on wiki shows a code that don't show us the constructos/desctructors of the objects at all:

```
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>

void write_to_file (const std::string & message) {
    // mutex to protect file access
    static std::mutex mutex;

    // lock mutex before accessing file
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    // try to open file
    std::ofstream file("example.txt");
    if (!file.is_open())
        throw std::runtime_error("unable to open file");

    // write message to file
    file << message << std::endl;

    // file will be closed 1st when leaving scope (regardless of exception)
    // mutex will be unlocked 2nd (from lock destructor) when leaving
    // scope (regardless of exception)
}
```

The definition I found for [lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) also cites it is "RAII-style":

> The class lock_guard is a mutex wrapper that provides a convenient RAII-style mechanism for owning a mutex for the duration of a scoped block.

On the example, the RAII is implemented on the mutex class, or in the lock_guard class? Or is not implemented on a class at all?

Comment: How are `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard` not objects (non primitive types)? It's completely unclear for me what you're asking about.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so, this example implements RAII ouside a object constructor/destructor? And this is considered RAII?

Comment: Is It ironic as there are mainly objects in this sample?

Comment: I think you guys are missing the point. There are objects, but no code for constructors or destructors, which are stated in most RAII definitions I found.

Comment: @fotanus _"so, this example implements RAII ouside a object constructor/destructor?"_ Uhm what please? What makes you think there's no constructor/destructor for e.g. `std::lock_guard`?

Comment: @fotanus the code is inside the `mutex` and `lock_guard` classes, you just don't see it.

Comment: `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);` that's object construction. Object is constructed (on the stack). So its destructor will be called at the end of the scope. Your question is unclear

Comment: @UmNyobe is it clearer now?

Comment: Since `std::lock_guard` is itself RAII implementation and can be used to implement RAII, your question is pretty useless.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you don't have to answer my question if you find it useless :-)

Comment: @fotanus Well, you can declare a class having a `std::lock_guard` member, what then? Your question is void. You have misconceptions what RAII means, that's all. I'm just reluctant to answer your question because there's no real question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is `lock_guard` who provides RAII ***for synchronization*** in the snippet you posted. `mutex` by its own doesn't follow the RAII idiom. RAII doesn't have to be provided by a separate object. For instance, `std::ofstream` provide both functionality for file output operation and RAII ***for the file state `open\close`***. Is it a freedom left to the designer.

> RAII = Resource Acquisition Is Initialization

ie Object creation implies resource acquisition and object destruction implies resource destruction. If you are doing acquisition or destruction somewhere else then you are not using RAII.

Comment: so lock_guard class is a RAII class? Mutex class is a RAII class? Or the RAII concept don't need to be bound to a class and can be in the main code?

Comment: A method/function call using the object, as the example from wiki.

Comment: This is a really cool answer. It clearly explains my question. This was the exact conclusion I got when reading the wiki example. But all other examples and definitions involve constructos/destructors of an object, so I think I'll have to wait for upvotes or a cannonical reference before accepting.

Comment: @fotanus You still don´t understand that these classes do have constructors and destructors. But the whole code is somewhere else, so you can´t see it.

Comment: @deviantfan I understand that. But the RAII concept shouldn't be on the constructors and destructors of those classes. Otherwise the code for those methods would be in the example.

Comment: @fotanus So the whole problem is that you think the example isn´t complete? It isn´t even possible to write "the" source for lock_guard etc. there, because there is more than one implementation (because there is more than one implementation of the whole C++ standard lib out there). An example here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00945_source.html#l00393

Comment: @deviantfan that is a really cool link and have help me a lot. So in fact the example on wiki is a terrible example. `lock_guard` class is a RAII class, `mutex` is not, and the example is the usage of a RAII class, not of an implementation of a RAII. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!

Comment: "mutex by its own doesn't follow the RAII idiom" Yes it does. It probably acquire and initialize a mutex from the underlying implemention (`pthread` on Linux) in its constructor, and release it in its destructor.

Comment: @Xaqq I am talking specifically about the synchronization issue here, not about allocation of the underlying native object. `std::mutex` doesn't acquire in the constructor, that's why `lock` is for... Why speculate when you can have a sample implementation : https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00945_source.html

Comment: @UmNyobe Acquire doesn't mean locking. I meant it as getting a mutex from the library implementing them (eg, `__GTHREAD_MUTEX_INIT_FUNCTION(&_M_mutex);`) in your exemple link. So indeed mutex uses RAII because the initialization of the underlying native object is done in the constructor. You do not need a `mutex.init()` call or something else before being able to use the mutex.

Answer (score 5):

RAII is a usage of constructors and destructors in C++ to ensure that successful acquisition actions are guaranteed to be undone.  The classic example is lock acquisition and release.

```
class mutex_guard {
public:
    explicit mutex_guard(mutex& lock): m_lock(lock) {
       m_lock.acquire();
    }
    ~mutex_guard() { m_lock.release(); }
private:
   mutex& m_lock;
};
```

When an instance of `mutex_guard` is created, it acquires the lock or it fails (if `mutex::acquire` throws).  If it does succeed, the guard object is fully instantiated and it's destructor is guaranteed to be called.  Therefore, if the mutex is successfully acquired, the paired called to `mutex::release` is guaranteed.

The canonical implementation is uses the guarantee that a fully constructed object will always be destructed when it leaves scope to ensure that acquired resources are always released.  In that sense, it uses objects and the Standard guarantees on the instance lifecycle to implement the requirements of the RAII idiom.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to change the question a bit for clarification. `On the example, the RAII is implemented on the mutex class, or in the lock_guard class? Or is not implemented on a class at all?` can you help me understanding this?

Comment: The RAII contract is implemented by the `mutex_guard` class.

Comment: But it can also be implement in a method/function body that uses the class, like wiki example? Or the RAII is in a omited object constructor/destructor?

Comment: Answering my own question here, as pointed by @deviantfan [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00945_source.html#l00393), the `lock_guard` class implements the RAII. If you add this to your answer, I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 2):

You can use objects' constructors and destructors for RAII. In fact, this is one of the most common usage of the idiom. For example, a very very simple smart pointer (probably the canonical example of RAII) can be implement like below (live on [<kbd>ideone</kbd>](http://ideone.com/aBhAiK)):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class RAIIpointer
{
private:
    T* _raw_pointer;
public:
    explicit RAIIpointer(T* managed): _raw_pointer(managed)  // acquiring resource
    {
        std::cout << "\t\tAllocating memory for single object\n";
    }
    ~RAIIpointer() // releasing resource
    {
        std::cout << "\t\tReleasing memory for single object\n";
        delete _raw_pointer;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class RAIIpointer<T[]> // array specialization
{
private:
    T* _raw_pointer;
public:
    explicit RAIIpointer(T* managed): _raw_pointer(managed) // acquiring resource
    {
        std::cout << "\t\tAllocating memory for array\n";
    }
    ~RAIIpointer() // releasing resource
    {
        std::cout << "\t\tReleasing memory for array\n";
        delete[] _raw_pointer;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Before entering RAII scope\n";
    {
        std::cout << "\tCreating a smart pointer...\n";
        RAIIpointer<int> smart_ptr(new int); // that's it, automatic release when scope ends
        RAIIpointer<int[]> smart_ptr_arr(new int[42]); // same
        std::cout << "\tDone with it\n";
    }
    std::cout << "After exiting RAII scope\n";
}
```

You can clearly see here how the ctor and dtor perform the allocation/deallocation. It is completely transparent for the client (main function here). That's exactly the idea behind `std::lock_guard`: its constructor acquires a `std::mutex`, its destructor releases it when the object goes out of scope.